# Show that $A=\{X\in\mathcal P(\mathbb Z),X=\{k,k+2\} \}$ is countable infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove this statement but I am stuck at surjective. Can I get verification on the injective part or pointers in the right direction? Thank you.

Consider the set $A=\{X\in\mathcal P(\mathbb Z),X=\{k,k+2\} \}$. Show that $A$ is countable infinite.

To prove that $A$ is countable, we must show that it is equinumerous to $\mathbb{N}$, so I must show that there is a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Proof:

$A$ is the collection of all the subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the form $\{k,k+2\}$. Then consider the function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Now suppose that $x,y\in A$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $\{x,x+2\}=\{y,y+2\}$, so $x=y$. Hence $f$ is injective.

I know I need to show that $range(f)=\mathbb{N}$ but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: What exactly is your function $f$? For example what is $f(\{-3,-1\}$? You should first establish a bijection with $\mathbb Z$.  Then you can use a well known bijection between $\mathbb Z$, and $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I came up with an answer and posted it at the following link: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3708068/784963

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to show that set $A$ is countable is to create a one-one function from $A \to \Bbb{N}$ (so you don't need surjectivity). 
Let
$$f\left(\{n,n+2\}\right)=\begin{cases}2^{n} & \text{ if } n \geq 0\\
3^{-n} & \text{ if } n <0.
\end{cases}$$
Now show that this function is one-one which will prove that $A$ is countable. Also show that the range is infinite, which will prove that $A$ is countable infinite.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually defined your function, so it makes no sense to check injectivity or surjectivity. I will give a hint and let you verify the details.

**HINT.** Define $f: A \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $\{k,k+2\} \mapsto k$.

Answer (score 0):

We first define a function that maps $\{k,k+2\}$ to $k$. So consider the function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with

$f(\{x,x+2\})=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}2x&,&x\text{ even}\\ 3x&,&x\text{ odd}\end{array}\right.$

Then we can show that a bijection exists.

Injection: Let $\{a,a+2\},\{b,b+2\}\in A$, such that $f(\{a,a+2\})=f(\{b,b+2\})$. If $a,b$ is odd, $a+2,b+2$ is odd, so we have $3a=3b$ and $3a+6=3b+6$.

If $a,b$ is even, then $a+2,b+2$ is even, so we have $2a=2b$ and $2a+4=2b+4$.  We clearly see that $a=b$, so $f$ is injective.

Surjection: Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite, we know that the set $A$ is infinite. This means that for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, there is an $a_k$ such that $f(\{a_k,a_k+2\})=k$. Thus, $f$ is surjective, so it is bijective.

Thus, $A$ is countably infinite.