# Consider the set $A=\{X\in\mathcal P(\mathbb Z),X=\{k,k+2\} \}$. Show that $A$ is countable infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $A=\{X\in\mathcal P(\mathbb Z),X=\{k,k+2\} \}$. Show that $A$ is countable infinite.

We first define a function that maps $\{k,k+2\}$ to $k$. So consider the function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with

$f(\{x,x+2\})=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}2x&,&x\text{ even}\\ 3x&,&x\text{ odd}\end{array}\right.$

Then we can show that a bijection exists.

Injection: Let $\{a,a+2\},\{b,b+2\}\in A$, such that $f(\{a,a+2\})=f(\{b,b+2\})$. If $a,b$ is odd, $a+2,b+2$ is odd, so we have $3a=3b$ and $3a+6=3b+6$.

If $a,b$ is even, then $a+2,b+2$ is even, so we have $2a=2b$ and $2a+4=2b+4$.  We clearly see that $a=b$, so $f$ is injective.

Surjection: Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite, we know that the set $A$ is infinite. This means that for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, there is an $a_k$ such that $f(\{a_k,a_k+2\})=k$. Thus, $f$ is surjective, so it is bijective.

Thus, $A$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Your function $f$ is not a function on set $A$, which is a set consisting of two-element subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is $P$ the set of prime numbers? If yes, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) says the problem is still open

Comment: You asked a very similar question about $2$ days ago at [Show that $A=\{X\in\mathcal P(\mathbb Z),X=\{k,k+2\} \}$ is countable infinite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3704914/602049). If you didn't find either of the $2$ answers there sufficient, you should have asked for more details. However, since you've written a new question instead, at the minimum as a common courtesy to help avoid duplication of efforts, you should have at least mentioned your earlier question with a link to it, along with an explanation of what it's missing & you're looking for here instead.

Comment: Sorry, I made a new question because I tried to prove it another way but I didn't post it in the other one because it said I shouldn't ask for help in the answer.

Comment: I changed the proof. Can I get verification that this is what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Your set $A$ can also be written as
$$
A = \big\{ \ \{ k, k+2 \} \ \colon \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \ \big\} = \big\{ \ \{ k, k+2 \} \ \colon \ k = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3,\pm 4, \ldots \ \big\}.
$$
Thus the map $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A$, $k \mapsto \{ k, k+2 \}$ is a natural bijection of $\mathbb{Z}$ with $A$.

So $A$ has cardinality equal to that of $\mathbb{Z}$, which in turn has cardinality equal to that of $\mathbb{N}$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your function $f$ seems to map naturals to naturals, not elements of $A$.

The best way to do this problem is to note that there's an obvious bijection by matching $\{k, k+2\}$ with $k$. So $|A| = |\mathbb N|$, which is clearly countably infinite.